# get_y() value of the image bottom in fpdf in python

Tags: python, fpdf

I'm using Python FPDF to generate pdf. The pdf generally contains text followed by images followed by text and so on. But the cells that contains text are overlapping with the images above them. I tried to calculate image length and pass that to set_y for next cell to avoid overlapping, still no luck. So I tried using get_y() but it returns the 'y' value of previous text cell instead of the bottom of the image.

So how can I get the 'y-coordinate' of the bottom of the image ?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I resolved it by using the pillow library.
The Pillow library will give us the height and width of the image in pixels. And if you divide it by 10 it will work as we needed.

After this, I am abled to get the y coordinate exactly below the inserted image. I inserted another image exactly below the previous image.

```
y = pdf.get_y()
img_height = Image.open(imagePath).height/10
y = y + img_height + 10
pdf.set_y(y)
```

That's how you will get it and to set the y coordinate I used `pdf.set_y(y)`.

Comment: Pillow will tell you the height of the image in *pixels*. What that corresponds to in millimeters or centimeters depends on at what resolution the image is displayed/inserted.

Comment: Pixel depends on your display device. If you know the physical size of the device and the resolution, you can figure out how many pixels per physical unit and extrapolate that from the point of origin of your image. Generally 1inch = 96 pixels